# I can not figure out how to make the code build blocks one by one

Tags: java, matrix, processing

This is my first time i pose a question here, I am frustrated because I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours now. Why is my code not building each cube separately. Code is supposed to fill the canvas horizontally with cubes, changing line after filling another line.

```
void setup() {
  size(600,600);
  background(0);
  frameRate(1);
}
int n=0;
int y=0;
int xCoord=0;
void draw() {
    while(n<10)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            rect(xCoord, y, 60,60);
            xCoord += 60;
        }
         xCoord = 0; n++; y+=60; 
         
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide more code, a [mcve]. Is this all you have (any other js or html)?

Comment: is this javascript or is this java?

Comment: uh javascript has no function return type

Comment: hi. I am working in Processing 3 and this is java

Comment: void draw() {
  while (n<10)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
      rect(xCoord, y, 60, 60);
      xCoord += 60;
    }
    xCoord = 0; 
    n++; 
    y+=60;
  }
}
The problem I have @depperm is that the script is building my entire canvas in one frame instead of placing each cube visibly in row.

Comment: sorry for not being able to provide proper information, it is my first time using java and I'm first year in college, need to make a simple animation in processing using java

Comment: I have to figure out why it is building the whole canvas in one frame

Comment: The code is incomplete.  We are not privy to your assignment or what else you have done.  See [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the draw function is called each frame. If you want to animate something, you gotta make sure each frame shows some new information.

Your while loop completes (and thus builds all the blocks) in **one** iteration of draw. Thus, you will also see **all** the blocks drawn after the first iteration of draw completes. Thus, you do not see them built one by one.

If you want to draw them frame by frame, you need to ensure that you change the amount of blocks between each iteration of draw.

pseudocode:

```
var currentAmountOfBlocks;

fun draw:
   // Draw currentAmountOfBlocks blocks.
   for (i = 0; i <= currentAmountOfBlocks; i++)
   {
       drawBlock();
   }
   currentAmountOfBlocks++
```

Processing would then call it like this for you, at your desired `frameRate`

```
draw(); // 1 block
draw(); // 2 blocks
draw(); // ... blocks 
draw(); // n blocks
```

You were basically doing:

```
fun draw:
   drawAllBlocks()
```

Processing calls that like this for you:

```
draw(); // all blocks
draw(); // all blocks
draw(); // all blocks
draw(); // all blocks
```

Yes, you have a while loop counting to ten blocks, but that completes before your first iteration of draw() completes.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Your explanation helped me understand better what I was doing !